# Multivariate Normal Orthant Probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, approximation

For [bivariate zero-mean normal distribution](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) $P(x_1,x_2)$, the quadrant probability is defined as $P(x_1>0,x_2>0)$ or $P(x_1<0,x_2<0).$

$P(x_1>0,x_2>0) = \frac{1}{4}+\frac{sin^{-1}(\rho)}{2\pi}$, where
$\rho \equiv corr(x_1,x_2)$

Is there an analytical solution for higher-dimensional [orthant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthant) probabilities?
For instance, for $X\sim N(0_{N\times 1},\Sigma_{N\times N})$, the orthant probability is defined as $P(X>0)=P(x_1>0,x_2>0,...,x_N>0)$

Comment: Terminology may be getting in your way here. Try searching *multivariate normal orthant probability* (or *multivariate normal orthant probabilities*). You'll find quite a lot of hits - papers with approximations, implementations in R, and so on.

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379378/probability-that-multi-dimensional-random-variable-is-positive/379414#379414