# Can we rule out $\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2 \pi (n-1)} \left( \sum_{\substack{i,j \in \{ 1, \cdots, n \} \\ i < j}} \sin^{-1} (\rho_{i,j}) \right)$?

Tags: probability, distributions, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am curious about orthant probabilities for the multivariate normal distribution for any finite dimension $n$. While [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) currently doesn't seem mention these quantities the Wolfram Mathworld entry for the [bivariate normal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) gives

$$\frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2 \pi} \left( \sin^{-1} \rho \right)$$

as the quadrant probability and similarly the [trivariate normal](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrivariateNormalDistribution.html) octant probability is given by

$$\frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4 \pi} \left( \sin^{-1} \rho_{1,2} + \sin^{-1} \rho_{1,3} + \sin^{-1} \rho_{2,3} \right).$$

The more general case appears to be difficult. It was asked about here in [*Multivariate Normal Orthant Probability*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67801/multivariate-normal-orthant-probability), but has equivalently been asked about in `math.se` in [*Probability that multi-dimensional random variable is positive?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379378/probability-that-multi-dimensional-random-variable-is-positive) and [*Multivariate gaussian integral over positive reals*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869502/multivariate-gaussian-integral-over-positive-reals).

Sometimes it is easier to evaluate a candidate guess to a problem than to rigorously derive something from first principles and definitions. Looking at the bivariate and trivariate cases led me to guess an n-dimensional generalization of these equations for the orthant probability.

$$\frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2 \pi (n-1)} \left( \sum_{\substack{i,j \in \{ 1, \cdots, n \} \\ i < j}} \sin^{-1} (\rho_{i,j}) \right)$$

I have started with some [sanity checks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanity_check).

- This equation agrees with the bivariate and trivariate cases.
- When there is no correlation we have $\frac{1}{2^n}$ probability equally for all orthants, which makes sense for a symmetric distribution.

The main irregularity that jumps out at me is the equation is undefined for $n=1$, but this is not necessarily a problem if we simply limit the generalization to $n \geq 2$. Of course in the $n=1$ case we should have $\frac{1}{2}$ probability either left or right of the mean, which agrees with the $\frac{1}{2^n}$ term.

Can we can rule this guess out?

Comment: The correct formula must be proportional to the determinant of a linear transformation that makes the distribution standard Normal.

Comment: After this transformation from Whuber, you get that the original orthant is now the shape of some sort of multidimensional polytope. Since the distribution is standard normal the distribution has spherical symmetry and has equal probability in all directions. The probability is then given by the amount of [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Solid_angles_in_arbitrary_dimensions) that the polyhedron 'occupies'. This geometric analogy may explain why you get these trigonometric relations.

Comment: I've found [a general solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4418242) in terms of a Taylor series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another check is what happens when you set one of the correlations to 1, effectively reducing the dimension from $n$ to $n-1$ (because two variables will be the same if the correlation is 1).

#### Examples of checks that work

- Reducing from $n = 3$ to $n=2$

  With $n=3$, if $\rho_{1,2}=1$ then $\rho_{2,3}=\rho_{1,3}=\rho$, so you get $$\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2\pi(3-1)}\left(\sin^{-1}\rho+\sin^{-1}\rho+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sin^{-1}\rho+ \frac{1}{8}$$
  which is equal to the formula of the $n=2$ case.
- Reducing from $n=2$ to $n=1$

  And with $n=2$, setting the correlation to 1 reduces the formula to $1/2$, which is the $n=1$ case.

#### Counter example that does not work

- Reducing from $n=4$ to $n=3$

  With $n=4$, if you set $\rho_{1,2}=1$, you get three distinct $\rho$s: $\rho_{2,3}=\rho_{1,3}$, $\rho_{2,4}=\rho_{1,4}$ and $\rho_{3,4}$. Two of these are pairs; one isn't. So, the formula will reduce to something of the form
  $$A+B\left(2\sin^{-1}\rho_{2,3}+2\sin^{-1}\rho_{2,4}+\sin^{-1}\rho_{3,4}\right)$$
  which can't match the $n=3$ formula.

So this general formula must be wrong.

Comment: I could initially not quickly get the idea from this answer by quickly reading it (I read it yesterday on my phone but did not upvote yet because I didn't got the idea, now today I have been reading it more carefully and get the idea). So I edited the answer a bit with some headings. I hope you like it.